# href # not linking to location on same page unless clicked twice

Tags: html, anchor, adobe-brackets

So I've searched high and low on the site and can't find an answer that addresses my problem specifically.

I tried making the links in the usual way - gave an id attribute, then used href# as it was a link on the same page - and they worked fine for a while, I think it was when I added pics to the page that they stopped working but I'm not sure. They only work now if I click on them twice - has anyone else experienced this issue?

I've made sure all elements eg body are closed, and none of the IDs are duplicated.

```html
<a href="#Early Life">Early Life</a><br />
<a href="#Career">Career</a><br />
<a href="#Equipment">Equipment</a><br />
<a href="#Techniques">Techniques</a><br />
<a href="#Dan's top 5 blues fusion guitarists">Dan's top 5 blues fusion guitarists</a>

<H2 id="Early Life">Early Life</H2>
<h2 id="Career">Career</h2>
```

Comment: Show us some code, when can't help you out of thin air...

Comment: If you provide some code, maybe we can help you

Comment: thanks, i tried putting code in but it was coming out blank

Comment: <a href="#Career">Career</a> , <h2 id="Career">Career</h2>

Comment: Hopefully you can see from above that I've done the anchor bit, and used the link to a section of the same page. I'm just confused at the fact that it was working fine for a good while, then just stopped!

Comment: [Seems to work for me](https://jsfiddle.net/o6m6obmk/), but I imagine that other code is involved. Please create a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I'll try here. So here's the code for all the links on my page: <a href="#Early Life">Early Life</a><br />
        <a href="#Career">Career</a><br />
        <a href="#Equipment">Equipment</a><br />
        <a href="#Techniques">Techniques</a><br />
        <a href="#Dan's top 5 blues fusion guitarists">Dan's top 5 blues fusion guitarists</a> .

Comment: And here are the IDs I created - <H2 id="Early Life">Early Life</H2> , <h2 id="Career">Career</h2> etc etc.

Comment: There is other code but just simple things like tables, a picture, some headings etc. Help is much appreciated, I'm a beginner as you may have guessed!

Comment: Not sure if it's relevant but I'm using Brackets with live preview, and Chrome.

Comment: I could send the code for the entire page if anyone's feeling exceptionally helpful :)

Comment: Is there any JS or jQuery running when the link is clicked? Usually that's the culprit in scenarios where it takes multiple clicks to perform an action that should be done every time.

Comment: Have you tried it without spaces in the IDs?

Comment: @ duke: I've no Javascript whatsoever, I haven't even learned CSS yet :). @ Greg: just tried it there, no luck I'm afraid